# Issue Reading Meta Tags with jQuery-'Undefined'

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to select for the content attribute of a meta tag with the name 'description':

```
var description = $("meta[name='description']").attr("content");
```

From here I am appending the variable 'description' to a list using this:

```
$('#list').append("<li>"+description+"</li>");
```

The problem is that 'undefined' is being appended to the list. What can the issue be? For reference, the meta tag is in the head element with the format of:

```
<meta content="“contentHere”" name="description">
```

Where contentHere is some text. Could an issue be the two sets of quotation marks after 'content=' ? They are slightly different, but both are double quotes, and I am not sure what the distinction is.

Comment: It seems to work fine with your current code, http://jsfiddle.net/q32m91oa/ if you can add the full javascript & html code (only necessary parts), maybe I can have look for the issue

Comment: Apologies, I have just realized that I wasn't specifying the document to search meta tags in. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You must have multiple meta tags with name 'description' on your page. To get the first element you can use :

```
var description = $("meta[name='description']").first().attr("content");
alert(description);
```

To get any nth element from array use:

```
var descriptionElement = ($("meta[name='description']").get(2));
var description=$(descriptionElement).attr('content');
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rcugump7/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the issue. This is the only meta tag with name description, but I tried .first() regardless and it did not work.

Comment: What are you getting on your console?

Comment: Apologies, I have just realized my mistake (commented above). Thanks for your feedback!